# Как включить стили для шаблонов HTML с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

У меня есть основной шаблон HTML, который целиком представляет всю страницу.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content"><?php include_once($my_content_path); ?></div>
        <!-- стили шаблона $my_content_path здесь -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Как видите, в шаблоне включается какой-то неизвестный шаблон по пути `$my_content_path`. Как мне лучше всего включить его собственный файл стилей, если я знаю иерархию того, как они хранятся?

Также скажите, как лучше всего поступить с файлами стилей для шаблонов HTML?

Comment: лучше, если каждый шаблон подключаемый сам вернет вам стили, js и прочее, а вы их в конце вставите.

Comment: Какие есть практики а ПХП я не в курсе... Но для подключения стилей css на странице - достаточно создать теги style с нужными свойствами и значениями.

Comment: @teran я не очень понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Можете подробнее объяснить, как это будет происходить? (Я использую чистый PHP)